# Select * for reverse lookup

Tags: django, django-queryset, reverse-lookup

I've have three models in Django.

```
class Product(models.Model):
  name = mdoels.CharField()
```

```
class ProductCharateristics(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  description = models.TextField()
```

```
class ProductCharacteristicValues(models.Model):
  product_characteristic = models.ForeignKey(ProductCharacteristics)
  value = models.IntegerField()
  prduct = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

The list of characteristics may change, it's the same for all products and each characteristics can have multiple value.

I'd like to replicate with django ORM the following SQL statement:

```
select * from ProductCharateristics as pc left join ProductCharacteristicValues as pcv on pc.id = pcv.product_characteristics where pcv.product = 1
```

This query retrieves all rows and all columns from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
ProductCharacteristics.objects.filter(productcharacteristicvalues_set__product__id=1)
```

Comment: this will give the list of ProductCharacteristics without the columns from ProductCharacteristicsValues that I need in the template

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
ProductCharateristics.objects.filter(productcharacteristicvalues__product_id=my_product_id)
```

If you however want the characteristics with the values, then it makes more sense to query the `ProductCharacteristicValue` table and fetch the `product_characteristic` with it, so:

```
ProductCharacteristicValues.objects.filter(
    product_id=my_product_id
).select_related('product_characteristic')
```

This will return a `QuerySet` of `ProductCharacteristicValues` objects, but if you access `.product_characteristic` it will not make extra queries, since that data was added in the initial query.

Comment: I agree but it's not possible in the code as I need to display the list of Characteristics available if there aren't values related. Now I solved with an intermediate list filled in the view, but that means I lose part of the power of the database engine and SQL language. And performances decrese because I must loop on results and add some queries.

Comment: @Christian: I don't see why you need intermediate lists, you can just use `for pcv in qs: print(f'{pcv.product_characteristic.name}: {pcv.value}')` (for the second qs), this will *not* introduce extra queries, that is the power of the `.select_related`, that it includes it in the first query.

Comment: @Wilem Van Onsem: I agree but I have to display the list of names even if there are no values related. With the query written as in my sql statement I can use the same code and the same template to manage both cases; with your no.

Comment: Well the query you use will not include any values either. Yes you make a `LEFT JOIN`, but since you use a `WHERE pvc.product_id=1`, it will remove all `NULL` records anyway, so in that sense Django even optimizes the query w.r.t. the original on.

Comment: I agree but I can simply the code and leverage on SQL engine instead of using a loop in code in order to use one simple template. I can write:

result = "query" # where query is the subject of the question
if not result.exists:
  result = ProductCharacteristics.objects.all()

and in the template simply cicle on "result"

Sorry indentation is lost

Comment: @Christian: well the idea is that the ORM provides a way to (nearly) make it dialect independent, hence `MyModel.objects.filter(name__icontains=foo)` will translate this to any dialect as a case-invariant substring match. But I think a more important and often underestimated feature is that a `QuerySet` is an object that you can pass, and thus further filter down, order, etc. That is the core of how Django's mixins often can do pagination without the programmer having to worry about that, or permission and authorization checks in the DRF.

Comment: @Christian: so yes, you can write raw queries, in fact Django has some documentation on that, but it severely limits what Django can do, since the core functionality is about models that define how data looks like, this is richer than just a record in the database, since it contains extra validation, and logic to go through `ForeignKey`s for example, and finally allows to write a `ListView` only specifying the model/queryset for example, and pagination, filtering, etc. can be done automatically.

Comment: I agree! queryset is very useful and the abstraction it assures is very powerful and this is why I like Django. I just wanted to understand if I missing something. Thx